# What kind of integral is this, and how do you solve it?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I have to solve this integral:

> $\int_T(x^2+y^2)dx dy \ \ \ $ where $\ \ \ T=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2<1\}$

Now, *what gets me confused is that i have to integrate only with respect to $x$ and $y$ but not $z$*. The fact is that i have no idea on what this even means geometrically, **is this a double integral on a 3d domain?**

**At first** i didn't even noticed that and i managed to solve the integral (at least i believe) **as if it was:**

> $\int_T(x^2+y^2)dx dy dz \ \ \ $ where $\ \ \ T=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2<1\}$

switching to spherical polar coordinates since $T$ represents a sphere of radius $1$:

> $=\int_0^\pi d\theta\int_0^1 d\rho\int_0^{2\pi} \rho^2\sin^2(\theta)(\cos^2(\phi)+sin^2(\phi)) \ d\phi= \\ 
> =\int_0^\pi d\theta\int_0^1 2\pi\rho^2\sin^2(\theta) \ d\rho= \\ 
> =\int_0^\pi\frac{2}{3}\pi\sin^2(\theta) \ d\theta = \frac{\pi^2}{3}$

But the correct answer is $\frac{8\pi}{15}$ and i don't know how to get to that.

Comment: Typo in the source material, perhaps?

Comment: @T.Bongers i don't believe, it is more plausible that i'm not understanding something since the exercise comes from a recent exam in my uni, anyway this is the copy/paste of the source material:  $\int_T(x^2+y^2)dxdy$ where $T=x^2+y^2+z^2<1$

Comment: The most likely error is that you did polar coordinates transformation, which means the determinant of the jacobian is $\rho$. You should do spherical transformation instead (even if the $z$ does not appear) which should give you an additional term

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral is indeed 
$$\iiint (x^2+y^2) \, dxdydz$$
You made an error in computation. Note that $x^2+y^2$ is the distance to the $z$ axis, thus this can be thought of as the *moment of inertia*

$$I  =  \rho \iiint (x^2+y^2) \, dxdydz $$

where $\rho = \frac{M}{V}$ is the density of the sphere. But it is well known that

$$I = \frac{2}{5}MR^2 = \frac{2}{5}M$$
so, we are left with

$$\iiint (x^2+y^2) \, dxdydz = \frac{I}{\rho} = \frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{4\pi}{3} = \frac{8\pi}{15}$$

I leave it to you to properly compute the integral, now that is clear you have made an error.